# How do i position 1 div behind another one

Tags: html, position, z-index

So i am building a footer for my website and i want to position 1 div behind another one.

The first div is just a black background going from left to right fullscreen. So this div is going outside of the standard borders of the website.

```
#special_div {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 40px;
    text-align: middle;
    background-color: #000;
    z-index: -2;
    top: 775px;
}
```

The second div is just a div with content, links, search bar etc. This div stays without the borders of the website.

How do i position the black background behind the second div? I cannot merge it into 1 div because either the content goes out of the borders or the background stays inside the borders.

Is there any solution for my problem?

Example:

http://jsfiddle.net/hmc5v1rc/

Comment: The answer is on your question `tags`.

Comment: I'd start by validating your HTML. You can see from all the red in that fiddle that you have problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just do something like this?

```
CSS

ul{overflow:hidden}
li{float:left;padding:10px}

HTML 

<div style="background:black">

  <div style="width:1000px;margin:0 auto">
    <ul>
     <li><a title="" href="#">Link</a></li>
     <li><a title="" href="#">Link</a></li>
     <li><a title="" href="#">Link</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: style="width:1000px;margin:0 auto"

That is what i was looking for. It looks so obvious once i have the solution. Thanks alot for the help.

Comment: You're welcome. Good luck with the rest of your project.

Answer (score 1):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>How do i position 1 div behind another one</title>
</head>

</head>
<style type="text/css">
.div{position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 40px;
    text-align: middle;
    background-color: #000;
    z-index: -2;
    top: 775px;
    color:#FFF;
}
#div{
    color:#FFF;
}
</style>
<body><div class="div"> 
  <div id="div">Content for  second "div" Goes Here inside 1st div</div>
</div>
</body>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It would be the right way to do it in most cases however in this case it makes the content jump out of the website borders. The background div is fullscreen but the website itself is not. The content from the second div should stay within the borders.